# Can't create new android emulator in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

When I try to create a new emulator in the emulator manager For First time, I come across this page:

[image]

If you look at the bottom left of the image, You see that two fields "Processor" and "OS" are empty!
Why???
Can anyone help?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you update your Android SDK?

Comment: Hi, have a check with [Android SDK Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=windows#sdk-manager). And you could share the screenshot of **Platforms** and **Tools** in question.